# R layout() for ggplot inside function

Tags: r, function, layout, ggplot2

I have several general functions drawing a `ggplot`. Now I want to combine them into new plots, but somehow `layout()` does not work.

I have made this example to show my point:

```
plot_func_1 = function(){
  data1 <- data.frame(matrix(c(1:10), ncol=2))
  colnames(data1) <- c("name", "value")
  ggplot(data = data1) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = 1, y = value))
}

plot_func_2 = function(){
  data2 <- data.frame(matrix(c(11:20), ncol=2))
  colnames(data2) <- c("name", "value")
  ggplot(data = data2) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = 1, y = value))
}

plot_func_1_func_2_combined = function(){
  mat <- matrix(c(1,2), ncol = 2)
  layout(mat, width = c(0.5, 0.5))
  plot_func_1()
  plot_func_2()
}

plot_func_1_func_2_combined()
```

`plot_func_1_func_2_combined()` should combine `plot_func_1()` and `plot_func_2()` into one graph. But instead, only the second plot is shown. How can I change that?

Additional information: This problem does not seem to exist with the basic `plot` function, here it works:

```
plot_func_1 = function(){
  plot(1:5)
}
plot_func_2 = function(){
  plot(10:15)
}

plot_func_1_func_2_combined = function(){
  mat <- matrix(c(1,2), ncol = 2)
  layout(mat, width = c(0.5, 0.5))
  plot_func_1()
  plot_func_2()
}
plot_func_1_func_2_combined()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `grid.arrange()` from package `gridExtra` instead of `layout()`:

```
library(gridExtra)

plot_func_1_func_2_combined = function(){
 grid.arrange(plot_func_1(),plot_func_2(), ncol=2)
}

plot_func_1_func_2_combined()
```

[image]